# Spark Yarn running 1000 jobs in queue

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, oozie

I am trying to schedule 1000 jobs in Yarn cluster. I want to run more then 1000 jobs daily at same time and yarn to manage the resources. For 1000 files of different category from hdfs i am trying to create spark submit command from python and execute. But i am getting out of memory error due to spark submit using driver memory.

How can schedule 1000 jobs in spark yarn cluster? I even tried oozie job scheduling framework along with spark, it did not work as expected with HDP.

Comment: Command we used generate from our python script shown below. /usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/spark/bin/spark-submit --class xxx.xxx.xxx --master yarn-cluster --total-executor-cores 6 --executor-memory 2G --driver-memory 1G --queue default xxx-1.0.0.jar <args>

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you might not need 1000 jobs to read from 1000 files in HDFS. You could try to load everything in a single RDD as well (the APIs do support reading multiple files and wildcards in paths). Now, after reading all the files in a single RDD, you should really focus on ensuring if you have enough memory, cores, etc. assigned to it and start looking at your business logic which avoids costly operations like shuffles, etc.

But, if you insist that you need to spawn 1000 jobs, one for each file, you should look at `--executor-memory` and `--executor-cores` (along with `num-executors` for parallelism). These give you leverage to optimise for memory/CPU footprint.

Also curious, you are saying that you get OOM during spark-submit (using driver memory). The driver doesn't really use any memory at all, unless you do things like `collect` or `take` with large set, which bring the data from the executors to the driver. Also you are firing the jobs in `yarn-client` mode? Another hunch is to check if the box where you spawn spark spark jobs has even enough memory just to spawn the jobs in the first place?

It will be easier if you could also paste some logs here.

Comment: we know reading the multiple files in single RDD  but file size is huge we want yarn to schedule the resource instead of handling it within application. Trigger multiple jobs parallel will improve our system performance, we don't want to use executors or future task to do that from application level.

Comment: Command we used generate from our python script shown below. /usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/spark/bin/spark-submit --class xxx.xxx.xxx --master yarn-cluster --total-executor-cores 6 --executor-memory 2G --driver-memory 1G --queue default xxx-1.0.0.jar <args>

Comment: And you are getting OOM exceptions on the driver? If you get it on the executor, you need to give it more memory or check for partition sizes.

Comment: we increased the memory and partition size still did not work